# Nodejs API querying mongodb using date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, isodate

I am having trouble querying mongodb using user's birth date. The client application is sending birth date as a string in "MM-DD-YYYY" format.
I am getting no result although the user is an my database. How do I structure my application query in order to convert date inside a string to ISODate?

Here is the client request

```
{"firstName": "Mark",
  "lastName": "Tony",
  "birthDate": "06-25-1990"
}
```

Here is my query

```
db.user.findOne({
  'firstname': req.body.firstName,
  'lastname': req.body.lastName,
  'dob': req.body.birthDate
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> First of all make sure you convert dob object into date format from
>   the client side and convert object received on server into date too.

```
var date = new Date(req.body.birthDate) //converting into date format 
date = date.toISOString() // converting to iso format date
```

> similarly send data to server from client side in similar manner ! I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use JS Date object to convert string to ISO Date.

[More Info : JS Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: Not enough detail, please reference which parts of the link you added to your response actually answer the question. Need to be specific. Read the SO guidelines before posting.